# Difference in meaning between 'While I was reading a book' and 'While I read a book'?

Tags: difference, progressive-aspect

What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences?

1. While I was reading a book, I found an interesting article.
2. While I read a book, I found an interesting article.

I learned that in an ordinary case, we should put 'ing' form in the sentence including 'while'.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning.

Comment: @Khan There is a difference in meaning. Why else would English retain two separate forms, the simple past and the past progressive?

Comment: The first one sounds more natural (reading), because as TRomano pointed out below, it describes the process of reading, whereas to say "while I read a book" subtly implies that you read the entire book in one sitting. Though everyone would still understand your meaning with the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a book is not instantaneous like an explosion, or the blink of an eye, but an activity that requires some time. Nonetheless, when we use the past tense of the verb, as you do in your examples, it normally is understood to mean "to read a written work *in its entirety*" and not "to read *page by page*".

> I read that book when I was in high school.

Therefore, when we wish to refer to a past act of reading in a manner that emphasizes the *ongoing* activity, sentence by sentence, page by page, chapter by chapter, we use the continuous:

> While I *was reading* that book I found an article that interested me.

When we wish to refer to the activity of reading without emphasizing its ongoing physical/mental aspect and without the implication of completion, we can use the simple past in conjunction with a word like **while** which expresses duration:

> While she knitted near the fireplace, her sister read a book near the window.

But when we use the simple past in that way, the idea of activity-happening-in-time is absent, or at the very least unexpressed. It is as though we were describing a moment frozen in time, a woodcut, a *tableau vivant*.

Comment: I was just about to comment on the "I read while she knitted" case, using **exactly the same example**!

Comment: While she read minds her sister astral projected.